# How to pass multiple columns into uniroot as parameters

Tags: r, sapply

My task now is to solve a equation like `eqn(a,b,c)`, from which a, b, c each is a  column from a data. How to pass these columns to `uniroot` to solve roots at the same? I guess maybe `sapply` is useful here.

As alistaire suggested, I paste the details as followed:

the equation is like:

```
     eqnt <- function(T,l,fn,m,EI) { T - fn^2*m/l^2 - EI }
```

and Now the parameters are all (l,fn,m,EI) loaded into a dataframe, say `df`. I intend to solve all the equations with the parameters in `df`.

```
    L        m       EI       fn
 1 10 6.190004 9988.997  6.59710
 2 10 6.190004 9988.997  8.01847
 3 10 6.190004 9988.997  9.21858
 4 15 6.190004 9988.997 10.27676
 5 15 6.190004 9988.997 11.23391
 6 15 6.190004 9988.997 12.11441
```

How coud I?

When I tried followed code, defining a function and using `mapply`:

```
rootfun <- function(l,fn,m,EI){
     uniroot.all(eqnt,l,fn,m,EI,lower=0.8e5, upper=3.5e5,
                 interval=c(0.8e5,3.8e5))
 }

 res <- mapply(rootfun,l=data$L,fn=data$f.4,m=data$m,EI=data$EI)
```

the error arises:

```
 Error in f(xseq, ...) (from #8) : argument "mm" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Probably `mapply`, but you need [to make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pmap but without some data to work on its hard to answer your question. See for example:

```
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c("apple", "banana", "cherry"),
  pattern = c("p", "n", "h"),
  replacement = c("x", "f", "q"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
pmap(df, gsub)
```

Explanation - name your data you need to loop over in-line with the inputs of your function (in this case `uniroot`). Pass the data frame to pmap along with the function.